# passing parameter from view to action in controller

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a beginner to MVC

My View code

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        height: 500,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Accounts',
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var ln = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ln))';
            var profileID = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.profileID))';
            var title = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.title))';
            var active = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.active))';
            alert(active);
            var link = '@Url.Action("accountPartial", "BillingProfile")?ln=' + ln + '&profileID=' + profileID + '&title=' + title + '&active=' + active;
                    //link = link.replace(-1, ln);
                    //link = link.replace(-2, profileID);
                    $(this).load(link);

                },
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 200
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 200
                }
            });
            $("#opener-modal").click(function () {
                $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My Controller action

```
public ActionResult accountPartial(string title,bool active,int ln = 0, int profileID = 0)
    {
        List<AccountCode> model = db.AccountCodes.ToList();
        ViewBag.ln = ln;
        ViewBag.profileID = profileID;
        ViewBag.title = title;
        ViewBag.active = active;
        return PartialView("_AccountPartial", model);
```

Here When i enter title having space (eg:Check Account) then my controller action "accountpartial" is not called 
and when i enter title without any space (eg:check) then my actionName is called 
What must the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: u mean which title ? title of dialog box or the one that you are passing in action method?

Comment: title means my parameter which i am passing to the Url.action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the space in the title is not being url encoded correctly. Try using `encodeURIComponent()` to solve this.

```
var link = '@Url.Action("accountPartial", "BillingProfile")?ln=' + ln + '&profileID=' + profileID + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title) + '&active=' + active;
```

Just an idea. Can't be sure.

Comment: Andrew you are absolutely right it worked flawlessly.. thanks a lot for your help.. U saved my time :)